# Biweekly topic challenge: paleoclimatology [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge

I made a [post](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347/earth-science-biweekly-topic-challenge) asking for topic ideas for the challenge, and the highest scoring [suggestion](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347/earth-science-biweekly-topic-challenge/350#350) is for [paleoclimatology](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paleoclimatology).

Please use the tag [paleoclimatology](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paleoclimatology) when posting questions for this challenge, and remember to keep the site quality at a good level.

In two weeks, on December 3rd, I will tally up the results to see how we did, in an answer below this post. Feedback? Comment below this post or find me in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13909/what-on-earth). Have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the period that the challenge ran, we received 6 questions tagged [paleoclimatology](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paleoclimatology):

- [Release mechanism for methane clathrate at the PETM](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2871/release-mechanism-for-methane-clathrate-at-the-petm)
- [Hypotheses about Silurian carbon isotope excursions?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2897/hypotheses-about-silurian-carbon-isotope-excursions)
- [Did a gamma ray burst contribute to the Ordovician mass extinction?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2898/did-a-gamma-ray-burst-contribute-to-the-ordovician-mass-extinction)
- [How global was the Bonarelli Oceanic Anoxic Event?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2913/how-global-was-the-bonarelli-oceanic-anoxic-event)
- [What, if any, paleoclimate data can be derived from igneous rocks?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2914/what-if-any-paleoclimate-data-can-be-derived-from-igneous-rocks)
- [Current consensus on the Messinian Salinity Crisis](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/current-consensus-on-the-messinian-salinity-crisis)

These questions have attracted 6 answers. Here are the participants:

**Askers:**

[image: profile for plannapus at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]

[image: profile for sabre-tooth at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]

[image: profile for michael at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]

**Answerers:**

[image: profile for sabre-tooth at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]

[image: profile for richard at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]

[image: profile for plannapus at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]

[image: profile for fumblefingers at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]

Comment: I think it's safe to say that the challenge was not a great success.

Comment: @Michael it was decent though.

Comment: @Michael It has been definitely [worse than some](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1958/biweekly-topic-challenge-rescue-organizationscompleted), but also [better than others](http://meta.sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/217/biweekly-topic-challenge-ask-about-population-completed). If the pattern repeat in the next few challenges, maybe we can think about adding an incentive, such as a bounty or something.

Comment: @plannapus maybe it's too early to run this challenge just yet. Wait a few months, see the site's traffic increase.