# Biweekly topic challenge: mesoscale-meteorology [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge

I made a [post](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347/earth-science-biweekly-topic-challenge) asking for topic ideas for the challenge, and the highest scoring [suggestion](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347/earth-science-biweekly-topic-challenge/348#348) is for [mesoscale-meteorology](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mesoscale-meteorology).

Please use the tag [mesoscale-meteorology](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mesoscale-meteorology) when posting questions for this challenge, and remember to keep the site quality at a good level.

In two weeks, on December 19th, (if I remember this time) I will tally up the results to see how we did, in an answer below this post. Feedback? Comment below this post or find me in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13909/what-on-earth). Have fun!

Comment: [Last challenge's results](http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/374/20).

Comment: Wouldn't it be worth it to add here [casey's definition of the tag](http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/348/87) since it's a new tag created specifically for the challenge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the period that the challenge ran, we received 1 questions tagged [mesoscale-meteorology](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mesoscale-meteorology):

- [What's with this anomaly in this sounding (the CAPE and CIN readings)?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/3079/whats-with-this-anomaly-in-this-sounding-the-cape-and-cin-readings)

This question has attracted 1 answers. Here are the participants:

**Askers:**

[image: profile for kaz at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]

**Answerers:**

[image: profile for casey at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]