# Biweekly topic challenge: economic-geology [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge

I made a [post](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347/earth-science-biweekly-topic-challenge) asking for topic ideas for the challenge, and the highest scoring [suggestion](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347/earth-science-biweekly-topic-challenge/349#349) is for [economic-geology](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economic-geology).

Please use the tag [economic-geology](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economic-geology) when posting questions for this challenge, and remember to keep the site quality at a good level.

In two weeks, on January 4rth, if I remember, I will tally up the results to see how we did, in an answer below this post. Feedback? Comment below this post or find me in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13909/what-on-earth). Have fun!

Comment: [Last challenge's results](http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/375/20). 1 asker & 1 answerer.

Comment: Can you use older questions? I asked this a week or so before the challenge started, but it seems pretty on-topic: http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/3006/when-did-will-peak-conventional-oil-happen

Comment: @naught101 No; too bad :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the period that the challenge ran, we received 2 questions tagged [economic-geology](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economic-geology):

- [Where does the lithium in Salar de Uyuni comes from?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/3121/where-does-the-lithium-in-salar-de-uyuni-comes-from)
- [Ore deposits buried under cities?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/ore-deposits-buried-under-cities)

These questions have attracted 3 answers. Here are the participants:

**Askers:**

[image: profile for michael at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]

**Answerers:**

[image: profile for sabre-tooth at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]

[image: profile for peter-jansson at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]

[image: profile for geogaffer at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]