# Biweekly topic challenge: antarctic [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge

I made a [post](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347/earth-science-biweekly-topic-challenge) asking for topic ideas for the challenge, and the highest scoring [suggestion](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347/earth-science-biweekly-topic-challenge/376#376) is for [antarctic](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antarctic).

Please use the tag [antarctic](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antarctic) when posting questions for this challenge, and remember to keep the site quality at a good level.

In two weeks, if I remember, I will tally up the results to see how we did, in an answer below this post. Feedback? Comment below this post or find me in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13909/what-on-earth). Have fun!

Comment: Last challenge's results: [2 questions & 3 answers](http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/393/20).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the period that the challenge ran, we received 7 questions tagged [antarctic](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antarctic):

- [Is there conclusive evidence for the Antarctic Circumpolar Current developing after the glaciation of Antarctica?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/3201/is-there-conclusive-evidence-for-the-antarctic-circumpolar-current-developing-af)
- [Active rifting in Antarctica?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/3202/active-rifting-in-antarctica)
- [What is the age of the Gamburtsev Mountains?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/3205/what-is-the-age-of-the-gamburtsev-mountains)
- [What geophysical knowledge have we learned by the construction of IceCube?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/4230/what-geophysical-knowledge-have-we-learned-by-the-construction-of-icecube)
- [How strong can a glacial icequake get?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/4249/how-strong-can-a-glacial-icequake-get)
- [How much has the total transport of the Antarctic Circumpolar Current changed over time?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/4271/how-much-has-the-total-transport-of-the-antarctic-circumpolar-current-changed-ov)
- [Is Antarctic sea ice at record levels?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/4282/is-antarctic-sea-ice-at-record-levels)

These questions have attracted 5 answers. Here are the participants:

**Askers:**

[image: profile for sabre-tooth at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]

[image: profile for aretxabaleta at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]

**Answerers:**

[image: profile for plannapus at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]

[image: profile for sabre-tooth at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]

[image: profile for peter-jansson at Earth Science Stack Exchange, Q&A for those interested in the geology, meteorology, oceanography, and environmental sciences]