# Biweekly topic challenge: volcanology

Tags: discussion, challenge

I made a [post](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347/earth-science-biweekly-topic-challenge) asking for topic ideas for the challenge, and the highest scoring [suggestion](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/395/611) is for [volcanology](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/volcanology).

Please use the tag [volcanology](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/volcanology) when posting questions for this challenge, and remember to keep the site quality at a good level.

In two weeks, if I remember, I will tally up the results to see how we did, in an answer below this post. Feedback? Comment below this post or find me in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13909/what-on-earth). Have fun!

Comment: [Last challenge's results: 7 questions and 5 answers by 4 distinct users](http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/394/biweekly-topic-challenge-antarctic-completed).